# QGIS when using ESRI TTF characters to fill polygons, the characters displayed in the font panel do not match the previewed characters

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, font

In the QGIS Symbol Selector, when using ESRI TTF characters to fill polygons, the characters displayed in the font panel do not match the previewed characters. I am using the ESRI Cartography character set. My computer is installed ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap with right licence
[image]

Why is the character panel display different from preview pannel?